# Fluent NHibernate mapping discriminator

Tags: sql, fluent-nhibernate, mapping, subclass

I need to set more than one discriminate values for parent class. Is it possible to do and how?

For example:

**PARENT_CLASS**

```
DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("COLUMN_NAME", "X");
```

**CHILD_CLASS_1**

```
DiscriminatorValue("Y");
```

**CHILD_CLASS_2**

```
DiscriminatorValue("Z");
```

This is possible. But what if i have more than these 3 values in column `"COLUMN_NAME"`?

For example, if "P" and "Q" are also possible values for that column, what should I write?

`DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("COLUMN_NAME", "X","P","Q");` Obviously this is not possible to write. But I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 4):

the syntax for the CASE may vary for different sql databases

```
DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("").Formula("CASE COLUMN_NAME WHEN 'P' THEN 'X' WHEN 'Q' THEN 'X'  DEFAULT COLUMN_NAME");
```